# How to convert Open invoices into Paid state in odoo9 after doing payment?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view, odoo-website

I have exported invoice data from odoo7 and imported into odoo9.

When I go for register payment for those imported data of Open invoices, payment for those invoices can be done successfully but invoices state still remain same(i.e.Open) instead of Paid state.

I have already checked all configuration like checked on Allow Reconciliation in account, set income account etc. All configuration are proper as per requirement.

Can any one help me regarding it?

Comment: That question has nothing to do with programming at all. Please use the [Odoo Forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum) for this one.

Comment: 7 to 9 export.,.. please have a look on all fields in odoo 9 are satisfied